# Does the entropy of a random variable change under a linear transformation?

Tags: entropy, information-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable. If $Y=aX+b$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, is the entropy of $Y$ the same as the entropy of $X$?

Comment: The answer for continuous variables is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415435.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on whether $X$ is discrete or continuous.

### If $X$ is discrete

Let $R_X$ be the range of $X$ such that:
$$
R_X = \{x_1,x_2,...,x_N\}
$$
And let $P(X=x_i)$ be the probability mass function of $X$. The entropy of $X$ is:
$$
H(X) = -\sum_{i=1}^N P(X=x_i) \log{P(X=x_i)}
$$
Next, let:
$$
Y = aX+b
$$
Where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. This means that the range of $Y$ is:
$$
R_Y = \{y_1,y_2,...,y_N\} = \{ax_1+b,ax_2+b,...,ax_N+b\}
$$
And the probability mass function of $Y$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
P(Y = y_i) &= P(aX+b = y_i) \\
&= P\left(X = \frac{y_i-b}{a}\right) \quad i=1,2,...,N
\end{align}
$$
So the entropy of $Y$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
H(Y) &= -\sum_{i=1}^N P(Y=y_i) \log{P(Y=y_i)} \\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^N P\left(X = \frac{y_i-b}{a}\right) \log{P\left(X = \frac{y_i-b}{a}\right)} \\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^N P(X=x_i) \log{P(X=x_i)} \\
&= H(X)
\end{align}
$$

The entropy of $Y$ is the same as the entropy of $X$ in the case that $X$ is discrete.

### If $X$ is continuous

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function $p_X(x)$. Also, let $h(X)$ be the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Definition) of $X$ such that:
$$
h(X) = -\int_{x\in\mathcal{X}} p_X(x) \log{p_X(x)} \ dx
$$
Where $\mathcal{X}$ is the support of $X$. Next, let:
$$
Y = aX + b
$$
Such that:
$$
x = \frac{y-b}{a}
$$
And the probability density function of $Y$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
p_Y(y) &= p_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right) \cdot \left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right| \\
&= \frac{1}{|a|} p_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)
\end{align}
$$
The differential entropy of $Y$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
h(Y) &= -\int_{y\in\mathcal{Y}} p_Y(y) \log{p_Y(y)} \ dy \\
&= -\int_{y\in\mathcal{Y}} \frac{1}{|a|} p_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right) \log{\frac{1}{|a|} p_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)} \ dy
\end{align}
$$
Substituting $y=ax+b$ yields:
$$
h(Y) = h(X) + \log{|a|}
$$
This equation is only valid for $a \neq 0$. So, in the case that $X$ is continuous, then the differential entropy of $Y$ is **not** the same as the differential entropy of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $X$ takes at most countable many values, then for any function $f$, the entropy $H(f(X))$ of the random variable $f(X)$ cannot be greater than the entropy $H(X)$ of $X$. In short: $H(X) \geq H(f(X))$ for any $f$.

This is due to the monotonicity of the logarithm, implying
$$(a+b)\log(\frac{1}{a+b})=a\log(\frac{1}{a+b})+b\log(\frac{1}{a+b})\leq a\log(\frac{1}{a})+b\log(\frac{1}{a})$$
for any $a, b >0$. Now consider $A = \{x\in X(\Omega): \exists x'\in X(\Omega)\text{ with } x \neq x'\text{ and } f(x)=f(x')\}$ and notice that
$$H(X) - H(f(X)) = \sum_{x\in A}P(X=x)\log\Big(\frac{1}{P(X=x)}\Big)-\sum_{y\in f(A)}P(f(X)=y)\log\Big(\frac{1}{P(f(X)=y)}\Big).$$